# AddIn and AppRedirect.aspx is redirecting to eachother back and forth

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a simple provider hosted addin

When I take the url of the addin , ie the app web like http://my-azure-appweb.azurewebblabla.com and paste it in a browser and just watch the spectacle, I see that as soon as my app has loaded its redirects to its
appredirect-page (http://my-tentant.sharepoint.com/bla), which redirect back to
the app and so on and so forth.

CAn anyone explain this to me and how to just be able to visit the app page on (in my case) azure

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue should cause by you have custom redirect logic in your app web(http://my-azure-appweb.azurewebblabla.com), a app web is just a web application for your case.

Users should login SharePoint first usually, you could check the Token flow below.
[image]

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/context-token-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins